# Android: Can write to lib dir?

Tags: android, android-ndk

Is it possible to programmatically copy a file into, or create a symbolic link in the  /data/data/application_package/lib directory?

When trying to write to the lib directory, I always get permission denied error.
I have defined

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

Comment: how are you deriving the directory into which you will write the lib?

Comment: Manually specifying it, i.e.: /data/data/com.bubba.myapp/lib

Comment: so, now that i think about it ... i assume this is not allowed. why? because if you could do that, you could download arbitrary (malicious) code from the network making it available to your app.

Comment: There is no `WRITE_INTERNAL_STORAGE` permission in Android.

Comment: @JeffreyBlattman you actually can download arbitrary code and make it available to your app.  Even if this were blocked at the execute bit/dynamic linker level, you can map writable executable pages and load them up yourself - a capability upon which the DVM running in your app process relies for its JIT.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You cannot write to lib/, however you do not need to.

You can write to any non-reserved location within your your application's private storage area, and you can load a native library from any file on the device for which you have read and execute permission, using System.load() with the full pathname, rather than System.loadLibrary() with the short library name.

The external storage (sdcard) is mounted with a non-executable flag, but a file in your private storage directory would be a workable solution.  Just be sure to make it only writable by your application, so that something else can't change it behind your back (it is because you cannot protect external storage files from such modification that the external storage is non-executable)

Comment: Which locations are reserved?  (sorry, fairly new to android).

Comment: Well, lib/ obviously, not sure what else.  Probably best to just make your own subdirectory within your private storage area.

Answer (score 1):

if you want load so file ,you can use system.load(); you can copy so to data/package name/libs

and use system.load() to load so