# Android. Writing libraries to lib folder at runtime

Tags: android

I have learn that Android application libraries in "libs" project folder are written onto /data/data/[package_name]/lib folder. During runtime they are loaded from this location if needed.

I'm writing a taxi driver android application. We decided to perform it as a package of modules that are updated over internet if needed. So if there are updates only needed files are updated but not the whole apk. This already works! But we plan to add maps so that the driver can build a taxi drive root with a help from one of it and see it on the screen.

I started looking at Yandex Map Kit for Android. The thing is that this kit has a native library (even two versions of it, for distinct hardware) that is loaded via System.loadLibrary() at runtime. I want these .so files to be loaded over internet as modules, too, so I need a way to write my files into my app's /data/data/[package_name]/lib folder. Is that possible?

Comment: maybe the expansion library would be appropriate here? http://developer.android.com/guide/google/play/expansion-files.html

Comment: Just have read something. Think that this is of no help.

Comment: Have you read this SO question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11582717/android-can-write-to-lib-dir

Comment: Yes, I have read this. Looks like I can't get write access to lib folder :( The proposal in that question was to use some other internal storage folder for which write and execute access can be acquired. But I think there is no way to tell Android that loadLibrary() must load a library from this folder unless it is fully specified it the path parameter. The problem is that this Yandex Map Kit jar comes without sources, I can't override the code calling loadLibrary()

Comment: @Dmitiri - Ah, that is unfortunate. At worst you will have to bundle Yandex Map into your APK, and either have to check your server to prompt for update or have your store deliver it if you need to change Yandex.

Comment: I see :( But just an idea: what if I preload NDK library by myself from the location I want (not bundled with apk) before starting this Yandex Map Kit?

Answer (score 1):

Use this code:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private final static int FILE_WRITE_BUFFER_SIZE = 32256;
    String[] libraryAssets = {"libmain.so"};
    static MainActivity instance;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        instance = this;
        File libs = getApplicationContext().getDir("libs", 0);
        File libMain = new File(libs, libraryAssets[0]);
        File input = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), libraryAssets[0]);
        if(libMain.exists()){
            Log.v("Testing", "exist");
        }else{
            try {
                InputStream is = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(input), FILE_WRITE_BUFFER_SIZE);
                if(streamToFile(is, libMain)){
                     Log.v("Testing", "File copied");
                }
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                     Log.v("Testing", e.toString());
            } catch (IOException e) {
                     Log.v("Testing", e.toString());
            }
        Log.v("Testing", libMain.getAbsolutePath());
        }
    }

    private boolean streamToFile(InputStream stm, File outFile) throws IOException{
        byte[] buffer = new byte[FILE_WRITE_BUFFER_SIZE];
        int bytecount;
        OutputStream stmOut = new FileOutputStream(outFile, false);
        while ((bytecount = stm.read(buffer)) > 0){
            stmOut.write(buffer, 0, bytecount);
        }
        stmOut.close();
        stm.close();
        return true;
    }

    public static Context getContext(){
           return instance;
    }
}
```

And in the class where you need to load the library:

```
private static File libMain = new File(MainActivity.getContext().getDir("libs", 0), "libmain.so");

static{
    try {
        System.load(libMain.getAbsolutePath());
    }catch(Exception e){
        Log.v(Tag, e.toString());
    }catch(UnsatisfiedLinkError e){
        Log.v(Tag, e.toString());
    }
}
```